# How can I change the ImageButton from a different Layout?

Tags: android, layout

So I have basically two activities, and when I go back from the 2nd activity to the 1st activity, I want to change the transparency from the ImageButton in the 1st activity. How can I achieve this? (The code is from the 2nd activity)

```
public class StoreActivity extends Activity {

    ImageButton pokeb;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.store_layout);
        pokeb = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.pokeball);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();

        pokeb.setAlpha(1f);
    }
}
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you have two activities with different layouts and you want to change the UI of first activity when you return from second activity.

Comment: yeah right ^^ two activites ^^ instead of layouts,

Answer (score 2):

You can change the transpetancy of button on the FirstActivity when you navigate from FirstActivity to SecondActivity

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using `startActivityForResult()` for starting the second activity. Over in the second activity you can set data using `setResult()` and that will be received in your first activity in `onActivityResult()` when you come back to it where you can do the required changes.

There are numerous sources from where you can get the code for the above setup including [here](http://www.javatpoint.com/android-startactivityforresult-example) and [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply define a static variable (as a flag) in first activity (FirstActivity.java).

```
public static boolean changeImageButton = false;
```

And check if changeImageButton is true in onResume():

```
if (changeImageButton) {
    pokeb.setAlpha(1f);
    changeImageButton = false;  // reset the value.
}
```

In second activity, in onBackPressed():

```
FirstActivity.changeImageButton = true;
```